# React cannot read properties of undefined inside conditional statement

Tags: reactjs, typescript, conditional-statements

I'm fetching data from an API which returns an object that looks like this.

```
results: { 
    AT: {
          buy[],
          rent[]
},
    US: {
          buy[],
          rent[]}
}
```

And I'm having trouble checking whether the property US exists. This is resulting in a cannot read properties of undefined error. The way I'm attempting to do it looks like this.

```
{typeof(provider?.results.US.flatrate) !== undefined && provider?.results.US.flatrate.map()}
```

The data is stored inside provider using the useState hook.

```
const [provider, setProvider] = useState<Monetization>();
```

The way I'm fetching data from the API looks like this.

```
axios.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + movieId +
            "/watch/providers?api_key=my_key").then(res => setProvider(res.data));
```

Comment: add extra optional chaining: `provider.results?.US?.flatrate`

Comment: `typeof` always returns a **string**. No string is `=== undefined`. Either put quotes around `undefined` or remove `typeof`. (Also, `typeof` isn't a function, you don't need to wrap its operand in `()`.)

Comment: *"And I'm having trouble checking whether the property US exists. "* You haven't used optional chaining on `US`, just on `provider`. If `provider` isn't `null` or `undefined`, the rest of it is evaluated without any optional chaining. If it's just `US` that may be undefined, it's `provider.results.US?.flatrate`. You use the `?.` on each thing that may be nullish. If that's every level, it's `provider?.results?.US?.flatrate`. If it's just `provider`, it's what you have. If it's just `US`, it's what I showed earlier. The basic rule is that the `?.` comes after the thing that may be nullish.